# Application Context in SpringBoot Integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Integration test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ProductServiceIT {
}
```

When I run it I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'adminPostsController' defined in file
```

This AdminPostsController has nothing to do with this integration test. And is only called because it is in the Application Context.
Of course I could add it as @MockBean in my tests but this does not seem like the best solution.
Can somebody help me how to start the Application context only for this Service similiar to @WebMvcTest(ProductsController.class), or give me a hint to some other solution.

Comment: If you have any question or need more information just ask and don't just vote down. That does't help

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured from an invalid method in the respository and it look likes an error in the test context. Sorry for the the application context can be very confusing.